# Python : IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.6

In python i have this code

```
if record[0][1]:
```

the problem is.. when mysql does not return anything and thus..

```
record[0][1]
```

has no data..

this python code fails:

```
if record[0][1]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

i simply want it to move on to the "else" statement or simply consider this if statement as .. invalid given that

```
record[0][1]
```

has no value. or data.. ( incoming stuff from mysql )

Comment: You can always just `try: ... except IndexError: ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
try:
    if record[0][1]:
        # Do stuff
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: That look like an anti-pattern as in Python you would just access the tuple - surrounded by a try/except - but actually not test if the data exist. Ask forgiveness not permission.

Comment: i am also getting an error like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945860/getting-error-when-converting-a-pyscript-to-exe-using-py2exe

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `try...except` or use a short-circuiting check on outer tuple.

```
if len(record) > 0 and len(record[0]) > 1 and record[0][1]:
```