# getting error when converting a pyscript to exe using Py2Exe

Tags: python, indexing, tuples, exe, py2exe

I am new to this py2exe,

I have my script in cmd.py

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
print "Hello World!"
```

setup.py,

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['cmd.py'])
```

having both the files in same directory,

I ran,

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

and getting the below error,

```
G:\PyScripts>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    setup(console=['cmd.py'])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267, in _run
    builder.analyze()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 160, in analyze
    self.mf.import_hook(modname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
    self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 388, in _scan_code
    for what, args in self._scan_opcodes(code):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 417, in _scan_opcodes
    yield "store", (names[oparg],)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Please help on this, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Seems like an anaconda issue

Comment: No py2exe is not working in Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Check your python version if it is 3 please try it with python version 2 because py2exe is developed for python2